# Automatically Update Table From Another PHPMYADMIN

Tags: database, datatable, phpmyadmin

I have a existing table Sign-Up which list the users and state an option if they would like to subscribe to the news letter. So in the column (in Table Sign_Up) for newsletter it states "YES" if this has been checked.

I Also have a second table called Subscribers..  suppose i want to add all or specific(column) values of an existing Sign_Up  record if the data states Yes they want to subscribe to newsletter.

The purpose of this is to have any records which have said yes to newsletter to update and save to my subscribers table.

Can this be done automatically within phpMyadmin?

Could Triggers help with this?